# Consuming Java REST service with AngularJS (issue with UPDATE, DELETE)

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest

I have implemented a REST service with Java and all HTTP methods work correctly when I test it with Postman. Now I decided to learn more about AngularJS and added it for consuming the REST service. The GET request works fine and all products are displayed on an html page. But for some reason Delete and Put methods do not work at all. And I'm having trouble to figure out what causes such behaviour.

I have noticed that the problem arises with methods that involve product id. The entity Product.java has an id field named *prod_id.*

**app.js**

```
angular.module("AppProducts", [])
.constant("baseUrl", "http://localhost:8080/webstore/product")
.controller("ProductsCtrl", function ($scope, $http, baseUrl) {

    $scope.currentView = "table";

    //Works correctly
    $scope.showAll = function () {
        $http.get(baseUrl).success(function (data) {
            $scope.products = data;
        });
    }
    //if product exists, copy it, otherwise new empty
    $scope.editOrCreate = function (product) {
        $scope.currentProduct = product ? angular.copy(product) : {};
        $scope.currentView = "edit";
    }

    $scope.create = function (product) {
        $http.post(baseUrl, product).success(function (product) {
            $scope.products.push(product);
            $scope.currentView = "table";
        });
    }

    $scope.update = function (product) {
        $http({
            url: baseUrl + product.prod_id,
            method: "PUT",
            data: product
        }).success(function (modifiedItem) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.products.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.products[i].prod_id == modifiedItem.prod_id) {
                    $scope.products[i] = modifiedItem;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $scope.currentView = "table";
        });
    }

    $scope.delete = function (product) {
        // HTTP DELETE
        $http({
            method: "DELETE",
            url: baseUrl + product.prod_id
        }).success(function () {
            $scope.products.splice($scope.products.indexOf(product), 1);
        });
    }

    // Save changes
    $scope.saveEdit = function (product) {
        if (angular.isDefined(product.prod_id)) {
            $scope.update(product);
        } else {
            $scope.create(product);
        }
    }

    $scope.cancelEdit = function () {
        $scope.currentProduct = {};
        $scope.currentView = "table";
    }

    $scope.sortType     = 'brand'; // set the default sort type
    $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
    $scope.searchProduct   = '';     // set the default search/filter term

    $scope.showAll();

});
```

**'table' view**

```
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th width="100"></th>
                    <th width="100"></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
                    <td>{{product.brand}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.productName}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.price}}</td>

                    <td><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="editOrCreate(product)">Edit</button></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(product)">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**RestController 'delete' method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteProduct(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

        Product product = productService.getProductById(id);
        if (product == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity(new CustomError("Unable to delete. Product with id " + id + " not found."),
                    HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        productService.deleteProduct(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Product>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

Comment: try changing url to url: baseUrl + "/" + product.prod_id. @samba

Comment: @simba: please mark it as aswer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be the problem. When you are appending the url like this

```
baseUrl + product.prod_id // let product.prod_id = 1
```

you would get resulting string as http://localhost:8080/webstore/product1 which is not defined in your backend. Try changing the assignment to something like this:

```
baseUrl + "/" + product.prod_id
```

Or you cold just add an `/` at end of baseurl. Like this:

```
.constant("baseUrl", "http://localhost:8080/webstore/product/")
```

Comment: If this was the problem, you can log the REST service URI in the browser console to check if it's correct. Like so:
`console.log(baseUrl + product.prod_id);`

Comment: @Muhammed Neswine Thank you. That helped!